Payoff Matrix with Mixed Strategy and Simplex
How can I find the optimal strategic probabilities for a given payoff matrix using simplex? For example, suppose I had the following payoff matrix:




Player 2 Strategy 1
Player 2 Strategy 2
Player 2 Strategy 3




Player 1 Strategy 1
0
-1
2


Player 1 Strategy 2
5
4
-3


Player 1 Strategy 3
2
3
-4



Where WLOG from Player 2's perspective, I can choose a strategy with probability p1, p2 and p3. The constraints are then that:
p1 + p2 + p3 = 1
But I am unsure how to proceed from here?
